# Blockchain synchronization fails, bus error

Tags: monerod, synchronization

I am using monerod 0.10.3.1 on Arch Linux. Towards the end of the process the synchronization with the blockchain fails:

```
2017-05-29 09:20:27.451 [P2P1]  WARN    net.dns 
src/common/dns_utils.cpp:531    WARNING: no two valid MoneroPulse DNS 
checkpoint records were received
2017-05-29 09:20:27.902 [P2P3]  INFO    global  
src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:293 
[66.228.41.201:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block 
candidate: 1237496 -> 1320640 [Your node is 83144 blocks (115 days) 
behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
 Bus error (core dumped)
```

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 5):

A bus error here is almost invariably due to a corrupt blockchain, so I'm afraid the only way out is to resync:

- delete the chain (the files in in ~/.bitmonero/lmdb)
- start monerod again, and wait for it to resync

You can get more info on that particular error, by running monerod again after running, in the same terminal: `ulimit -c unlimited`, then running gdb on the core which will be generated after the crash:

`gdb monerod core*`

Then, in gdb:

`bt`

You'll most likely find a stack trace crashing somewhere in the LMDB code, but if not, I'm interested to know where.

Answer (score 0):

```
monero-gui-v0.18.3.1/monerod  --log-level 4
2024-03-07 22:22:22.529I Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.3.1-release)
2024-03-07 22:22:22.530I Moving from main() into the daemonize now.
2024-03-07 22:22:22.530I Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2024-03-07 22:22:22.530I Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2024-03-07 22:22:22.530T Blockchain::Blockchain
2024-03-07 22:22:22.530I Initializing core...
2024-03-07 22:22:22.530T BlockchainLMDB::BlockchainLMDB
2024-03-07 22:22:22.530T BlockchainLMDB::get_db_name
2024-03-07 22:22:22.530I Loading blockchain from folder /home/wozza/.bitmonero/lmdb ...
2024-03-07 22:22:22.530D option: fast
2024-03-07 22:22:22.530D option: async
2024-03-07 22:22:22.530D option: 250000000bytes
2024-03-07 22:22:22.530T BlockchainLMDB::open
2024-03-07 22:22:22.530W The blockchain is on a rotating drive: this will be very slow, use an SSD if possible
2024-03-07 22:22:22.530T BlockchainLMDB::need_resize
2024-03-07 22:22:22.530D DB map size:     5090132736
2024-03-07 22:22:22.530D Space used:      3955585024
2024-03-07 22:22:22.530D Space remaining: 1134547712
2024-03-07 22:22:22.530D Size threshold:  0
2024-03-07 22:22:22.530D Percent used: 77.7108  Percent threshold: 90.0000
Bus error (core dumped)
```

- ✗  gdb monero-gui-v0.18.3.1/monerod core*

```
GNU gdb (Debian 13.2-1) 13.2 Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html> This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law. Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details. This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu". Type "show configuration" for configuration details. For bug reporting instructions, please see: <https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>. Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help". Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"... Reading symbols from monero-gui-v0.18.3.1/monerod... [New LWP 326598] [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled] Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1". Core was generated by `monero-gui-v0.18.3.1/monerod'. Program terminated with signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
#0  0x000055a5cf334f8a in mdb_page_search_root () (gdb) bt
#0  0x000055a5cf334f8a in mdb_page_search_root ()
#1  0x000055a5cf335165 in mdb_page_search ()
#2  0x000055a5cf3354bf in mdb_cursor_first ()
#3  0x000055a5cf33416b in mdb_cursor_get ()
#4  0x000055a5cf3345ee in mdb_page_alloc.isra ()
#5  0x000055a5cf33ae13 in mdb_cursor_touch ()
#6  0x000055a5cf33b430 in mdb_cursor_put ()
#7  0x000055a5cf33ef8a in mdb_dbi_open ()
#8  0x000055a5cf2ef96c in (anonymous namespace)::lmdb_db_open(MDB_txn*, char const*, int, unsigned int&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
#9  0x000055a5cf32d134 in cryptonote::BlockchainLMDB::open(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int) ()
#10 0x000055a5cf0a78d4 in cryptonote::core::init(boost::program_options::variables_map const&, cryptonote::test_options const*, std::function<epee::span<unsigned char const> const (cryptonote::network_type)> const&, bool) ()
#11 0x000055a5ced78950 in daemonize::t_core::t_core(boost::program_options::variables_map const&) ()
#12 0x000055a5ceda09d3 in daemonize::t_internals::t_internals(boost::program_options::variables_map const&) ()
#13 0x000055a5ced2406e in daemonize::t_daemon::t_daemon(boost::program_options::variables_map const&, unsigned short) ()
#14 0x000055a5ceda2054 in daemonize::t_executor::run_interactive(boost::program_options::variables_map const&) ()
#15 0x000055a5ceda56be in bool daemonizer::daemonize<daemonize::t_executor>(int, char const**, daemonize::t_executor&&, boost::program_options::variables_map const&) ()
#16 0x000055a5cecee98a in main ()
```